# Яндекс карты, как получить строку поиска в переменную?

Tags: javascript, яндекс-карта-api

Я получаю координаты найденной точки в переменную.
Мне еще необходимо получить строку поиска с адресом в переменную.

```
ymaps.ready(init);
function init(){
var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
    center: [55.764094, 37.617617],
    zoom: 11,
    controls: ['fullscreenControl', 'typeSelector']
      }, {
        searchControlProvider: 'yandex#map'
    });
    var searchControl = new ymaps.control.SearchControl({
        options: {
            fitMaxWidth: true,
            maxWidth: [660, 660, 660]
        }
   });
myMap.controls.add(searchControl);
 
        // Подписка на событие выбора результата поиска.
        searchControl.events.add('resultselect', function (e) {
        // Получает массив результатов.
        var results = searchControl.getResultsArray();
        // Индекс выбранного объекта.
        var selected = e.get('index');
        // Получает координаты выбранного объекта.
        var point = results[selected].geometry.getCoordinates();
        alert(point);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Мне подсказали решение.

```
ymaps.ready(function () {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
        center: [55.764094, 37.617617],
        zoom: 11,
        controls: ['fullscreenControl', 'typeSelector']
    }, {
        searchControlProvider: 'yandex#map'
    });
     
    var searchControl = new ymaps.control.SearchControl({
        options: {
            fitMaxWidth: true,
            maxWidth: [660, 660, 660]
        }
    });
    myMap.controls.add(searchControl);
 
    searchControl.events.add('resultselect', function(e) {
        var searchRequestString = searchControl.getRequestString();// получить строку запроса
        alert(searchRequestString);
         
        var results = searchControl.getResultsArray();
        var selected = e.get('index');
        var point = results[selected].geometry.getCoordinates();
        alert(point);
    });
});
```